# flex-wrap not working on my div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

At 928px breakpoint, I am looking to achieve that:

1. My right column (`.vd-right-col`) needs to be placed at the bottom of the page. (I have tried to achieve this by setting `flex-wrap:wrap;` but it isn't working.)
2. The two images inside this column need to be placed side by side.

However, it just isn't responding. Any ideas why?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*Vivid Global Styling*/

html {} body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
li,
span {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.wht {
  color: #fff;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/*Vivid Page Settings*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
}
.vd-hide {
  display: none;
}
.vd-settings-wrapper {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.vd-user-settings {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 0 21px;
}
.vd-currency-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 1px 2px;
}
.vd-language-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 2px 0 2px;
}
/*Vivid Main Navigation*/

.vd-nav-wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  height: 78px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 18px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-logo-img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*Vivid Checkout Settings*/

.vd-cart-wrapper {
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.vd-cart-selector {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -11px 31px 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: -9px;
}
/*Vivid Main Wrapper*/

.vd-page-container {
  /* width: 100%; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  /* max-width: 1280px; */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* flex-direction: row-reverse; */
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  flex-direction: row;
}
/*Vivid Grid*/

.vd-grid h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid p,
span {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.vd-grid h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h3 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h4 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid {
  display: flex;
  /* width: 1262px; */
  width: 98.6%;
  margin: 13px auto;
}
.vd-grid-left-col {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  /* float: left; */
  flex-basis: 90%;
  /* width: 980px; */
  /* width: 77.6%; */
  /* float: right; */
  /* flex-direction: row; */
  /* display: -webkit-inline-flex; */
  display: -inline-flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}
.vd-grid-right-col {
  height: px;
  /* width: 265px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 29%;
  /* width: 26.8%; */
  /* float: right; */
}
.vd-grid-main-box {
  /* margin: 10px; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 391px;
  background-color: #000029;
  /* padding: 3.2%; */
  padding: 2%;
}
.vd-grid-main-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.vd-grid-sub-box {
  /* margin: 5px; */
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 30.8%;
  height: 171px;
  background-image: url(../img/granda_hj.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: #000029;
  /* padding: 0.9%; */
  /* float: left; */
  /* padding: 0.9%; */
  /* margin: 0 0 1% 0.2%; */
  margin: 0 0;
}
.vd-grid-xtra-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 303px;
  background-image: url(../img/tst_img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #000029;
  /* padding: 10px 20px; */
}
.vd-text-wrap {
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* position: relative; */
  top: 340px;
  left: 0px;
}
.vd-margin-top {
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.vd-margin-right {
  /*! margin-right:10px; */
  margin-right: 0.5;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.vd-margin-left {
  /*! margin-left:10px; */
  /* margin-left: 0.8%; */
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.vd-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
/*Vivid Footer*/

.vd-footer {
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  /* padding-bottom: 55px; */
  background-color: #000029;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -moz-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
.vd-widget-area {
  display: flex;
  /* padding: 15px 0 10px; */
  border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
  /* max-width: 1260px; */
  margin: 0 auto 0px;
}
.vd-footer-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26%;
  padding-right: 60px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-footer-links {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 30px 25px 0;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: outside none;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.vd-footer-links li {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a:hover {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.vd-signup {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 305px;
  width: 26%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.vd-sub-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Vivid Payment Icons*/

.vd-payment-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #a7a7a7;
}
.vd-footer-linklist .vd-social-icon:before {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Social Icons';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-payment-options {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options ul {
  display: block-inline;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options li {
  display: block-inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.american-express:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.bitcoin:before {
  content: "\f006";
}
.jcb:before {
  content: "\f028";
}
.master:before {
  content: "\f02d";
}
.paypal:before {
  content: "\f033";
}
.visa:before {
  content: "\f045";
}
/*Vivid Copyright*/

.vd-copyright-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
/*Vivid Responsive*/

@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-resolution: 1.3dppx) {}@media screen and (max-width: 928px) {
  .vd-currency-selector {
    display: none;
  }
  .vd-language-selector {
    display: none;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 490px) {
    .vd-grid-sub-box {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .vd-currency-selector {
      display: none;
    }
    .vd-language-selector {
      display: none;
    }
    .vd-grid-right-col > div {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 1%;
      float: none;
    }
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="vd-navigation-wrapper">
    <div class="vd-settings-wrapper">
      <div class="vd-user-settings">
      </div>
      <div class="vd-currency-selector">
      </div>
      <div class="vd-language-selector">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-nav-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>Shop</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li class="vd-logo-img">
          <img src="img/vivid_logo.png" />
        </li>
        <li>Lookbook</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-cart-wrapper">
      <div class="vd-cart-selector"></div>
    </div>

  </div>




  <!--Mobile Navigation-->
  <nav class="vd-hide">
    <div class="menuIcon">
      <a href="#menuExpand">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="nav toggle-menu" href="#">
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="#firstSection"><img src="img/harva_logo.png"/></a></h1>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li data-menuanchor="firstSection">
        <a href="#firstSection" title="First Section">First Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="secondSection">
        <a href="#secondSection" title="Second Section">Second Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="thirdSection">
        <a href="#thirdSection" title="Second Section">Third Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fourthSection">
        <a href="#fourthSection" title="Fourth Section">Fourth Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection">
        <a href="#fifthSection" title="First Slide">First Slide</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection/1">
        <a href="#fifthSection/1" title="Second Slide">Second Slide</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<!--End Mobile Navigation-->

<div class="vd-page-container">
  <div class="vd-grid">
    <div class="vd-grid-left-col">
      <div class="vd-grid-main-box vd-margin-bottom">
        <div class="vd-text-wrap">
          <h1>Header Text</h1>
          <h2>Secondary Title</h2>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
        <h3>Header Text</h3>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left">
        <h3>Header Text</h3>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
        <h3>Header Text</h3>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-grid-right-col vd-margin-left">
      <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box">
        <h4>Header Text</h4>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box vd-margin-top vd-margin-bottom">
        <h4>Header Text</h4>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<footer class="vd-footer">
  <div class="vd-widget-area">
    <div class="vd-footer-text">
      <h4 class="vd-footer-title">V I V I D - SHOPIFY THEME</h4>
      <div class="rte">V I V I D is a customisable theme that looks and feels fantastic. Showcase your products on the visually stunning V I V I D Grid and choose your structure then let V I V I D do the rest!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-footer-links">
      <h4 class="vd-footer-title">HELP</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="" href="#">HELP | FAQ'S</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="#">RETURNS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="#">HOW TO SHOP</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="#">STOCKISTS</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-footer-links">
      <h4 class="vd-footer-title">POLICIES</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="" href="#">DELIVERY &amp; RETURNS POLICY</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="#">TERMS &amp; CONDITIONS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="#">SECURITY POLICY</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-footer-links">
      <h4 class="vd-footer-title">CONNECT</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="vd-social-icon facebook" href="#" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="vd-social-icon twitter" href="#" target="_blank">TWITTER</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="vd-social-icon instagram" href="#" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="vd-social-icon vimeo" href="#" target="_blank">VIMEO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-signup">
      <h4 class="vd-footer-title">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h4>
      <div class="wht">HTML Block to be added here for embedded email capture forms</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vd-sub-footer">
    <ul class="vd-payment-options">
      <li class="vd-payment-icon american-express"></li>
      <li class="vd-payment-icon bitcoin"></li>
      <li class="vd-payment-icon jcb"></li>
      <li class="vd-payment-icon master"></li>
      <li class="vd-payment-icon paypal"></li>
      <li class="vd-payment-icon visa"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="vd-copyright-wrapper">
      <p class="vd-copyright">Copyright © 2017 V I V I D Themes.</p>
      <p class="vd-attribution">"Virtual Visual Merchandising"</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 928px media query, you have `flex-wrap: wrap` set to the right column:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 928px) {
    .vd-grid-right-col {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This enables wrap on the children of this container. But the container is `flex-direction: column`, which means it will wrap vertically, not horizontally.

Instead, try something along these lines:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 928px) {
    .vd-grid-right-col {
        flex-direction: row;
     }
    .vd-grid {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
     }
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5ofqtLp/)